# How do I find the class of the object that's assigned to a variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some code like this, where I don't know what class was assigned to `someObject`:

```cs
public ISomeInterface someObject;

public void DoThing()
{
    someObject.DoAnotherThing();
}
```

How can I find out what's the class of the object assigned to `someObject`? Is there a button in Visual Studio to show this? When I hover over `someObject` inside of `DoThing`, Visual Studio gives me a list of properties and their values on `someObject`, but it doesn't tell me what the class of `someObject` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *also* do the same thing while you're debugging. If you're stopped at a break point you can enter that expression in the Watch window below.

[image]

The type of the variable will show up in the Type column in braces, and you have to expand the Watch window very wide to see it. The Type column will look like this:

```
SomeNamespace.ISomeInterface {SomeNamespace.SomeClass}
```

Comment: How do you add something to the watch window? Is there a keyboard shortcut? Is there a right-click / context menu option?

Comment: Just click where it says _Add item to watch_ and type it in. You can also drag objects into the watch window and drop them but I don't like that so much. And **yes** you can right click the object and `Add Watch`. Happy coding!

Comment: Wait, no, it does work, but you have to expand the Watch box really wide. It looks like `SomeNamespace.ISomeInterface {SomeNamespace.SomeClass}`.

Comment: I edited your answer to include this information and accepted it, thanks!

Comment: I like the edit, thanks. Would you consider deleting your comment that begins _This doesn't work_ because then the reader has to go down the list to see _Wait...it does..._ :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while writing the question. There isn't a way to see this in Visual Studio directly as far as I can tell (if someone figures it out please post another answer), but we can do it within C#:

```cs
System.Type type = someObject.GetType();
string typeFullName = type.FullName;
```